# How do I sort nested list of objects in kotlin and update that to the original list?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, data-structures, collections

So, I have a nested mutableList which I need to sort but I can't get it to sort. The model class is as follows: As you can see it has a model inside that it has ChildrenItem and Children Item can be contain inside.

```
@Keep
data class ItemsItem( @field:SerializedName("children")
    var children: MutableList<ChildrenItem?>? = null)


@Keep
data class ChildrenItem(  @field:SerializedName("children")
    var children: MutableList<ChildrenItem?>? = mutableListOf(),
)
```

The code to sort the nested mutableList is as follows:

```
 itemList.forEach { itemsItem ->
                    itemsItem?.children?.forEach { airportItem ->
                        airportItem?.children?.sortBy { it?.name }
                    }
                }
```

In the above code when I access the itemList next time the nested two objects, children here are not sorted by name. I also tried CASE_INSENSITIVE method but it's not working.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger!

Comment: I did. But still couldn’t get it working @Jorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected:
https://pl.kotl.in/D2U_9OP7f

```
data class ItemsItem(
    var children: MutableList<ChildrenItem?>? = null
)


data class ChildrenItem(
    var children: MutableList<ChildrenItem?>? = mutableListOf(),
    val name: String
)

fun main() {
    val itemList = listOf(
        ItemsItem(
            children = mutableListOf(
                ChildrenItem(
                    name = "childItem",
                    children = mutableListOf(
                        ChildrenItem(name = "first"),
                        ChildrenItem(name = "second"),
                        ChildrenItem(name = "third"),
                        ChildrenItem(name = "four")
                    ),
                ))
        )
    )
    println("Before $itemList")

    itemList.forEach { itemsItem ->
        itemsItem.children?.forEach { airportItem ->
            airportItem?.children?.sortBy { it?.name }
        }
    }
    println("After $itemList")
}
```

Result:

Before [ItemsItem(children=[ChildrenItem(children=[ChildrenItem(children=[], name=first), ChildrenItem(children=[], name=second), ChildrenItem(children=[], name=third), ChildrenItem(children=[], name=four)], name=childItem)])]

After [ItemsItem(children=[ChildrenItem(children=[ChildrenItem(children=[], name=first), ChildrenItem(children=[], name=four), ChildrenItem(children=[], name=second), ChildrenItem(children=[], name=third)], name=childItem)])]